# Bo-Katan Kryze publishing history Prior to the Mandalorian?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

What is the publishing history of the version of Bo-Katan Kryze who appears in the Disney+ live action series of the Mandalorian?

What was the real world date of her first appearance and where did that appearance occur, and did she then appear in another franchise or media after that before appearing in the Mandalorian?

For example, was she in any video games, comics, animated series, or novels?

Comment: Wookieepedia is famously not a great source for solid canon in-universe facts, but it is really good at keeping track of associated works.  https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bo-Katan_Kryze

Comment: Could you summarize and put in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 5):

From what I’ve discovered, Bo-Katan Kryze’s first appearance was the Clone Wars Season 4 Episode 14: “A Friend in Need”. This episode was released on January 13, 2012.

Sources:

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bo-Katan_Kryze
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo-Katan_Kryze#Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars